# How does (org-agenda-todo arg) work? What does the argument mean?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, documentation, todo, arguments

By trial and error I have found that in org-agenda `(org-agenda-todo 'done)` marks the entry at point as "DONE".

Can you explain why?

How can I modify the argument to the `org-agenda-todo` function (or which other function should I use) to mark the entry some other state, e.g. "WAITING"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org-agenda-todo` calls the `org-todo` function interactively and in doing so, the it passes its own argument as it is to `org-todo`<sup>1</sup>.

From `C-h f org-todo`, you will get a complete understanding of what the values of ARG mean to `org-todo` (and `org-agenda-todo`):

```
org-todo is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `org.el'.

(org-todo &optional ARG)

Change the TODO state of an item.
The state of an item is given by a keyword at the start of the heading,
like
     *** TODO Write paper
     *** DONE Call mom

The different keywords are specified in the variable ‘org-todo-keywords’.
By default the available states are "TODO" and "DONE".
So for this example: when the item starts with TODO, it is changed to DONE.
When it starts with DONE, the DONE is removed.  And when neither TODO nor
DONE are present, add TODO at the beginning of the heading.

With C-u prefix arg, use completion to determine the new state.
With numeric prefix arg, switch to that state.
With a double C-u prefix, switch to the next set of TODO keywords (nextset).
With a triple C-u prefix, circumvent any state blocking.
With a numeric prefix arg of 0, inhibit note taking for the change.
With a numeric prefix arg of -1, cancel repeater to allow marking as DONE.

When called through ELisp, arg is also interpreted in the following way:
‘none’             -> empty state
""(empty string)  -> switch to empty state
‘done’             -> switch to DONE
‘nextset’          -> switch to the next set of keywords
‘previousset’      -> switch to the previous set of keywords
"WAITING"         -> switch to the specified keyword, but only if it
                     really is a member of ‘org-todo-keywords’.
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I learned the above by looking at the source code of `org-agenda-todo`.

So it might be useful to email `emacs-orgmode@gnu.org` with a request to add more information to the doc-string of `org-agenda-todo`.. Something along the lines of "Refer to the documentation of `org-todo` to learn how ARG is used.".

Comment: Got it! To set the todo state to `WAITING` one needs to use `'"WAITING"` notation in `(org-agenda-todo '"WAITING")` and I was trying `'WAITING`.

Comment: BTW, do you know what `nextset` and `previousset` mean? Do they mean the first keyword in a set?

Comment: You do not use a quote before a string. The right way would be `(org-agenda-todo "WAITING")`. Also for that to work, `"WAITING"` has to be a part of `org-todo-keywords` alist. The next/previous set, I believe, is not very widely used (I may be wrong though). But for that to work, `org-todo-keywords` needs to contain multiple sequences; example:  `(setq org-todo-keywords '((sequence "TODO" "DONE") (sequence "TODO2" "DONE2")))`. Then `(org-todo 'nextset)` will toggle the todo keyword between `"TODO"` and `"TODO2"`.