# Org Mode: Where are `previousset`, `nextset` etc defined?

Tags: org-mode

I am doing a bit of keyboard rebinding and I have found that:

```
(org-todo "DONE")
(org-todo "TODO")
(org-todo "")
```

all work, but in the documentation, it says that I should be able to also use the symbols `nextset` and `previousset` as such:

```
(org-todo 'nextset)
(org-todo 'previousset)
```

I have searched the source code of `org-mode.el` and some of the `require` files too, but I cannot find the definition of `nextset` or `previousset`.

Below is my code:

```
(setq org-support-shift-select 'always)

(defun org-mode-todo-done-cycling-replacements ()
  (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "M-9") (lambda ()
                     (interactive)
                     (org-call-with-arg 'org-todo 'previousset)))
  (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "M-0") 'org-todo))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-mode-todo-done-cycling-replacements)
```

`M-0` works but `M-9` does not.

Am I supposed to `require` a library before? (Org-mode version is 8.3.3).

Comment: Relevant, very: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/21134/115 and [a comment to that answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21132/how-does-org-agenda-todo-arg-work-what-does-the-argument-mean/21134#comment32705_21134).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is simply replace the keyword with the next one, `(org-todo)` does it.

`org-todo-keyword` can contain several sequences (or *sets*) of keywords:

> org-todo-keywords is a variable defined in `org.el'.
>   Its value is ((sequence "TODO" "DONE"))
>
> Documentation:
>   List of TODO entry keyword sequences and their interpretation.
>   This is a list of sequences.

If I understand correctly, `nextset` and `previousset` are intended to select one of these sets.  So in your example `M-9` **does** work, it's just by default there's only one set of keywords.

`nextset` and `previousset` do not have to be defined anywhere, since they're just symbols.

Comment: Ok, so symbols don't *have* to be defined, they are just passed through like strings?

Comment: @TahirHassan Yes, see https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Symbols.html#Creating-Symbols